# Subtracting From Variables - Thonny Python

Tags: python, string, integer, thonny

I need help with subtraction with variables in python.

The response to what happens is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/TheBacsShop.py", line 16, in <module>
    balance_a -= 40
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'
>>>
```

And here is what I put:

```
balance_a -= 40
```

I really don't know whats wrong with my code. If you don't know what I am trying to do. I will explain:

So basically I want the 'player's balance' to start at any number **ABOVE** ***40***. But then subtract ***40*** from it. Without **setting** it to something. What would I do to achieve it?

(Whatever I am doing may be right just not available in THONNY PYTHON)

[EDIT]: OMG, the first of the awnser's u gave me are correct. But then (cue fail music) ***ANOTHER ERROR*** came up?!?!?!

Comment: check the type of balance_a, It should be int.

Comment: My guess is that you used `input()` somewhere in the code that you neglected to show, rather than `int(input())`. If you want something more than a guess, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Be specific; 'another error' doesn't mean anything if you don't tell us what error you're getting.

Comment: Oh, it was a ***corny*** joke. Plus another error came up. \/ \/ \/ \/ (Below at the bottom for what error it was.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'
```

is telling you that `balance_a` is a str (type string) and not an int (type integer). You need to make sure that `balance_a` is an integer. For example, '3' is a string; 3 is an integer.

`int(balance_a)` will cast the string ('3') into an integer (3), which you can then use for your subtraction.

The final code you're looking for is:

```
balance_a = int(balance_a) - int(gunCost)
print("You balance is now: $" + str(balance_a) + ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the variable to `int` before arithmetic ops:

```
balance_a = int(balance_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Timur Shatland Wait, what?

How would I set out the the subtraction ***It's self***

As I have put the 'int' infront of it already. Now what do I do? Like in here:  `balance_a = int(balance_a [What do I put here? eg - or 'minus' or what?] gunCost`

If you don't understand this completly pleas say.

(This is **NOT** another awnser)

Comment: You can use the 'add a comment' link instead of creating a new answer (or edit your original question). This is the code you're after: `balance_a = int(balance_a) - int(gunCost)` (in case gunCost is also a string).

Comment: Yes then this happens:     print("You balance is now: $" + balance_a + ".")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
>>>

Comment: That's correct. You cannot concatenate an integer (balance_a) with a string ('Your....'). You need to cast balance_a into string this time: `str(balance_a)`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the complete code. If that answers/solves your questions then accept it please.

Comment: Yessss, thanks so much! (It worked) Now I have to copy that brain power ***3 more times*** for other products xD